# Xcode: Module not found in embedded framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I dragged a .xcodeproj of a framework to top of my project, and embed the .framemork file, when I build the project, I'm getting error No such module in one of the files of the framework(the modules it can't find are Cocoapods libraries), but if I switch Scheme to the framework's, it builds successful, if I switch back to my project, it throws the same error in the framework.

I attached images below, you can also see that there are two different targets on the images.

[image: error]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Project Target Settings, under section `Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content` check that your dragged framework is `Embed & Sign` or `Embed without signing`